# What is the right place to keep Constants and Enums?

Tags: java, android

In application development, I often need to use 'Constants' and 'Enums'.As far as  I use the strategy, I keep all 'Constants' in a separate class named 'Constants' but I am not sure whether I should keep all Enums in a separate class as I use 'Constants'? or I should keep Enums in those class where I needed? Or should I also keep Enums in Contants class as 'static'.My question is what is the right place to keep all constants and Enums.

Comment: What ever you want. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a rule here, I usually try to keep constant values in the places where I use them. Try to **modularize** your code so that when you move a chunk of it, a class which does specific things, you don't need to go in the constants class and copy the N constants used by that module.

i.e.

If I use constants for bundle extras I keep then in the Activity that will eventually perform the getExtra(...) call

If I use shared preferences keys, I also keep them as constants and set them in the Activity or class or whatever which sets the value in the shared preferences.

For other type of constants, try also to use the **build.gradle** file and you'll have them in one place.

e.g.

`buildConfigField "String", "SUPPORT_EMAIL", '"support@mysite.com"'`

and you'll access them as `BuildConfig.SUPPORT_EMAIL`

or even resource values like:
`resValue "string", "branch_io_key", "key_live_xxxxx"`

which you access them like a normal string resource `R.string.branch_io_key`

For **enums**: again, try to keep your logic as much as possible inside a specific package, as a "module". If you, for instance, create a custom `View` which contains a builtin animation for whatever is in the background, and you for instance, have an enum for different types of animations for that `View` to perform, you can either:

1. have a package somewhere in `com.yourapp.ui.customviews.animatedView` where you have both the custom view class and also the enum, as a separate file
2. have your enum inside the custom view class

...so when you reuse the view in another project, you just need to copy either the entire package or just the View class and you'll make sure you've copied everything pertaining to that class.

One last thing: In case you use **strings** for, let's say, dialogs, and you've got some generic texts like "ok", yes", "no", "cancel", "success", "No internet connection available", etc and you've got them translated in X number of languages, try to keep them in a separate .xml file, so you can reuse the text values easily. You'll just copy these files of strings in your new project, instead of looking through a long .xml file and extract the strings that pertain to the dialog and move them to the new file.

So to **conclude**, try to keep your code in modules as much as possible, and keep everything "within", keep similar things together.

At least that's MY personal approach to constants and it's been ok so far.

Comment: I have a concern with your last point as you said "for string like yes, no try to keep separate xml file".What does it mean? What I got from you is to keep these string not string file, I should make separate xml file with whatever name?

Comment: yeah. So, for instance I use dialogs in my apps and those usually have the same text values assigned to them, like yes, no, cancel, etc, and I have a list of such strings in my strings.xml, but so I eventually moved them all to a separate strings file called "dialog_strings.xml" which I just copy entirely to my new projects and I use the necessary strings from there. It keeps everything modularized and reusable...

Comment: I also had a client which used the same app rater dialog and popups and whatnot for all their apps (they were similar), so I kept the text values for those in a separate xml file, and the constants and classes in a separate package, so I just copy pasted the entire package to the new projects and voila ...

Comment: Now, i am clear with confusions. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you a few tips on managing enums.

1. Place enums in its own file.

Since enums are usually kinda small and you won't write a lot of code in it, it's very easy to miss it if you put it in the same file as other code.  If you put it in its own file, you just need to look for the name of your enum in the file explorer, which IMO is way easier than looking for it in code.

2. Make good use of packages.

Don't just put all enums in the same package (e.g. `yourapp.enums`) unless they are related. Just like you do with classes and interfaces, you put enum files in suitable packages. Alternatively, you can put enums in a sub package of the suitable package. For example, a `Color` enum can be put into `yourapp.graphics.enums` package. This just makes it a whole lot easier to find them.

3. Place enums that are very closely related in one single file.

That just makes sense, right? If enums are closely related, you often need to edit them or add some methods or whatever. Therefore, it is convenient to put related enums together so you can easily edit them without opening a new file.

EDIT: I didn't notice that you also wanted to know where to store constants. Here are some more tips:

1. If a constant is only used in one class, declare the constant in that class.

C'mon, this is obvious. If a constant is only used in one class, it probably shouldn't be exposed to the world. Like, it just makes more sense. So, remember to declare those kinds of constants as `private static final` in the same class

2. If a constant is used in multiple classes, try to classify these constants.

For example, if you have some shared preferences keys as constants (which you should), make a `SharedPreferencesKeys` class and put them in there.

3. Again, use packages

This is basically the same idea as enums. Always use packages to classify your things.

Nevertheless, these are only some of my own habits. If you don't like them, it's fine.